# Not able to activate Conda Virtual Environment on Windows 8.1 machine

Tags: django, anaconda, virtual, conda, environment

I have been working with Atom text editor, Anacond and Python for a project and I am able to activate the virtual environment, however, when I type in the command to activate the virtual environment, it does nothing. I have attached a screenshot.

[image: Attached is the CMD command screenshot]

However, when I run the command, `conda info --envs` I am able to view the environment.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance for help.